# Java send midi message to device

Tags: java, midi

I have an APC40 MkII connected to a raspberry pi. On the pi, I have java running. With the java.sound.midi package, I can establish a connection to the APC and receive its midi messages without a problem. But after a lot of research I somehow still don't get how I can send midi messages to the APC.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
package lightorgansandbox;

import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.util.List;


public class MidiHandler {

public MidiHandler() {
    MidiDevice device;
    MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();

    for (MidiDevice.Info info : infos) {

        System.out.println("Info: '" + info.toString() + "'");

        try {
            device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info);

            List<Transmitter> transmitters = device.getTransmitters();

            for(int j = 0; j<transmitters.size();j++) {
                transmitters.get(j).setReceiver(new MidiInputReceiver(device.getDeviceInfo().toString()));
            }  

            Transmitter trans = device.getTransmitter();
            trans.setReceiver(new MidiInputReceiver(device.getDeviceInfo().toString()));

            device.open();

        }catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {}
    }
}

public class MidiInputReceiver implements Receiver {

    public String name;

    public MidiInputReceiver(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void send(MidiMessage msg, long timeStamp) {

        if (msg instanceof ShortMessage) {
            ShortMessage shortMessage = (ShortMessage) msg;

            int channel = shortMessage.getChannel();
            int pitch = shortMessage.getData1();
            int vel = shortMessage.getData2();
            System.out.println("Channel: " + channel);
            System.out.println("Pitch: " + pitch);
            System.out.println("vel: " + vel);

        }

    }

    public void close() {}

}

}
```

This all works just the way I want. But where in this can I send a message back to the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the message to the device's receiver.
From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-messages.html):

```
  Receiver rcvr = MidiSystem.getReceiver();  /* or device.getReceiver() */

  ShortMessage myMsg = new ShortMessage();
  myMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 60, 93);
  long timeStamp = -1;
  rcvr.send(myMsg, timeStamp);
```

Comment: You are a star CL. This works. But I'm still confused. I see no connection to a specific device in this code. How does MidiSystem.getReceiver() knows which device is meant. What if I have three different Midi controllers connected???

Comment: The MidiSystem.getReceiver() command works just fine. Although I still don't understand where MidiSystem knows where to send the command. If I use device.getReceiver() I get the following error:
    Exception in thread "main" 
javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: MIDI IN receiver not available
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice.createReceiver(AbstractMidiDevice.java:418)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice.getReceiver(AbstractMidiDevice.java:280)

Comment: I couldn't get an exact answer, but this might give some hints: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#getReceiver()

Comment: Found the full explanation on how the device is selected / you can select the desired device: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing-MIDI.html